# Property 'features' does not exist on type 'Feature<Point, { [name: string]: any; }>'

Tags: angular, d3.js, geojson, topojson

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to build a map of germany with Angular/d3. The map data is stored in a Topojson file plz_map_ger.json:

```
{
"type": "Topology",
"arcs": [...],
"transform": {...},
"objects": {
      "plz5stellig": {...}
      }
 }
```

This is my code to draw the map:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import * as t from 'topojson';
```

...

```
d3.json("../../assets/plz_map_ger.json")
  .then(function(top:any) {
    g.selectAll('path')
      .data(t.feature(top, top.objects.plz5stellig).features)
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('d', path)
      .attr("class","kreisgrenzen")
      .on("click", function() {
        d3.select(this).attr("class","selected-kreis");
      });
```

However I get the following compile error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'features' does not exist on type 'Feature<Point, { [name: string]: any; }>'.
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Edit: 
When I hover over the error in VS Code i get the following message:

```
Property 'features' does not exist on type 'Feature<Point, { [name: string]: any; }>'.ts(2339)
```

I use the following Topojson file (this file is a bit simplified, however the structure remains the same) created with mapshaper.org:
[gist.github.com/.../plz_map_ger.json](https://gist.github.com/chscheiber/3b5ddc4bf7c5dd574cd86389a45b6f4f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/topojson-client/index.d.ts) the function `feature()` returns either a `Feature` or a `FeatureCollection`. Only the `FeatureCollection` will have the `.features` attribute that you are looking for.

Checking the [code of the TopoJSON Package](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-client/blob/master/src/feature.js) (line 4 - 8) we can see that the a `FeatureCollection` is only returned, if the `topology` 
 has `GeometryCollection` as its `type`.

```
export default function(topology, o) {
  return o.type === "GeometryCollection"
  ? {type: "FeatureCollection", features: o.geometries.map(function(o) { return feature(topology, o); })}
      : feature(topology, o);
}
```

You are loading the `topology` asynchronously, so it is impossible for the compiler to know, whether its `.type` is `GeometryCollection` or not.

In order to solve the issue you will need to have the GeoJSON types installed (`npm i @types/geojson`).

You can then either set the type of a temporary variable

```
    ...
    d3.json("../../assets/plz_map_ger.json")
      .then(function(top:any) {

          // This row sets the temporary variable
          let mapFeatures: FeatureCollection = t.feature(top, top.objects.plz5stellig)

           g.selectAll('path')

          // We use the temporary variable here
          .data(mapFeatures.features)
          .enter()
          .append('path')
          .attr('d', path)
          .attr("class","kreisgrenzen")
          .on("click", function() {
            d3.select(this).attr("class","selected-kreis");
          });
      });
```

Or you could explicitly cast the collection to a Feature Collection (thanks to @altocumulus)

```
  ...
    d3.json("../../assets/plz_map_ger.json")
      .then(function(top:any) {
           g.selectAll('path')
          // explicit cast
          .data((t.feature(top, top.objects.plz5stellig) as GeometryCollection).features)
          .enter()
          .append('path')
          .attr('d', path)
          .attr("class","kreisgrenzen")
          .on("click", function() {
            d3.select(this).attr("class","selected-kreis");
          });
      });
```

Comment: the `feature(a, b)` function can either return a `GeoJSON.Feature` or `GeoJSON.FeatureCollection` which of the two it is is not decided in compile, but rather in runtime, because it depends on the `type` property of the asynchronously loaded topology.

Comment: So setting the type of `mapFeatures` to `GeoJSON.FeatureCollection`; correct? I should maybe update the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your discussion and your help! I have uploaded and linked the Topojson File I use in my Question.